# hibernate jpa with java configuration using spring instead of xml

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

As in the header, I'm trying to reconfigure my CRUD from `xml` to `Java` based configuration.

I'm stuck with `InternalResourceViewer`.

A bit of code here:

mvc config:

```
package kaczynski.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="kaczynski")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

 @Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}
}
```

My `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4">
<display-name>Animal Database</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/kaczynski/config/MvcConfig.java</param-value>
        </init-param>


    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And in my old applicationContext.xml where I held configuration to jpa, I have this one line:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="kaczynski" />
```

If I delete it, I cannot see views. I'm kinda confused about it because:

1. I have `@ComponentScan(basePackages="kaczynski")` annotation in my `MvcConfig.java` file.
2. I don't have any pointer to `applicationContext.xml` in my `web.xml`.

Do you see any solution for this?

Comment: where is you JPA config?

Answer (score 0):

here's a good blog post on configuring JPA with java.

http://www.baeldung.com/2011/12/13/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-3-1-and-
jpa/#javaconfig

in most of my apps i have a config file every piece - web, jpa, security, data sources, etc...

normally for JPA you need toconfig entity manager in config file that starts with

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
```

you also need a `@ComponentScan` so spring can discover things like `@Controller` or `@Service`